# C#: Use Coalesing or Ternary Operator With Datetime Nullable

Tags: c#

How do I use Null Coalescing Operator with Datetime Nullable in C#?
Trying to create single line statement, in a select in Linq query.
Following is not working

```
select new ProductRDto
{
    EffectiveEndDate = timeslice.EffectiveEndDate.HasValue ?? timeslice.EffectiveEndDate.Value.Year : null
```

Ternary Operator creates this error

> Error: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'

```
  EffectiveEndDate = timeslice.EffectiveEndDate.HasValue ? timeslice.EffectiveEndDate.Value.Year : null
```

> Error: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and 'null'

*trying to not utilize if-else statements

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? `HasValue` can be used with `?:` conditional operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming what you *actually* want is the year of `timeslice.EffectiveEndDate` if that's not null, or a null value otherwise, the simplest option isn't to use either the conditional operator *or* the null coalescing operator - use the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) instead:

```cs
int? year = timeslice.EffectiveEndDate?.Year;
```

You would use the null-coalescing operator to use a different value instead of `EffectiveEndDate`, e.g.

```cs
DateTime? date = timeslice.EffectiveEndDate ?? defaultEndDate;
```

If you want to use the conditional operator instead, you just need to specify that you want the `null` value to be of type `int?`:

```cs
int? year = timeslice.EffectiveEndDate.HasValue
    ? timeslice.EffectiveEndDate.Value.Year
    : (int?) null;
```

Comment: Why are you not preferring var keyword?

Comment: @VimalCK: To make the result type *really* clear for the purpose of the post.

Comment: @MarkThomas51: No, and please don't use comments to try to get attention to unrelated posts. Glad this helped you though.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up the null coalescing operator with the ternary operator.  You want to use just one `?`.

```
EffectiveEndDate = timeslice.EffectiveEndDate.HasValue
    ? timeslice.EffectiveEndDate.Value.Year : null;
```

Comment: Okay, right I was just addressing the difference between the two operators.